# Erro ao realizar chamada de PROCEDURE no SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sqlfiddle

Ao realizar a chamada de uma `PROCEDURE` no SQL Fiddle, é exibido o seguinte erro:

> DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL;
>   only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema
>   panel.

Na aba de construção de schema, utilizo a seguinte query:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( COD NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
                     DATESTART DATETIME,
                     DATEEND DATETIME);

  INSERT INTO TEST
  VALUES (1, '2019-03-29 10:20:57', '2019-04-29 10:20:57');

  CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST()
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TEST;
  END//
```

Na aba de execução de SQL:

```
CALL PROC_TEST()
```

Segue o [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63b9c/2/0) utilizado na criação e chamada da `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: André, poderia entrar no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para conversarmos sobre essa tag [tag:sqlfiddle]? Ficou bem confusa essas edições adicionando a tag.

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, estou no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

André, isto parece um BUG do SQL Fiddle no MySQL 5.6.

Outra thread ja foi respondida com isso em [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-triggers-stored-procedures-on-sqlfiddle-mysql).
Pedi para o konerak dar uma olhada no [Issue 5 no GitHub](https://github.com/zzzprojects/sqlfiddle3/issues/5) e na thread em [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-triggers-stored-procedures-on-sqlfiddle-mysql).

Notei que você está usando o char delimitador como `//` , mas o código utiliza `;` , mantenha todos utilizando `//` exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63b9c/2/0.

Entretanto para enriquecer a discussão e continuar a ideia do Bruno, os sequintes comandos poderiam ser utilizados para você entender melhor seu ambiente:

Apresentar as permissões atuais do usuário:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER()//
```

Materiais de referência:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute

Como sugestão para testar seu código e saber se o SQLFiddle está interpretando seus comandos utilize um select antes e depois:

```
select * from TEST//
call PROC_TEST()//
select * from TEST//
```

Exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e63b9c/2/0

Como proximos passos sugiro que você crie uma base MySQL em um docker e teste localmente pois neste caso o SQLFiddle não está atendendo o que promete.
Adicionamente como se tratar de um projeto no GitHub abra um Issue para o projeto. Como fiz para você aqui: https://github.com/zzzprojects/sqlfiddle3/issues/5

Comment: Apesar de estar usando outro caractere delimitador, isso não impactou na execução do código(o problema está no `run SQL`). Já fiz a melhoria na pergunta. O que quero é trabalhar no SQLFiddle já que não estou conseguindo.

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER()\\ ` não seria com o delimitador `//` ?

Comment: André, infelizmente como comentei na minha resposta isto parece um bug, coloquei mais um comentário no issue do github para te ajudar na resolução deste problema o mais rápido. Seria uma boa você entrar lá e colocar um comentário, talvez ajude. Eu acredito que sua pergunta está respondida no momento, parece não pode ser consertada sem alteração no código do SQLFiddle.

Comment: @AndréFilipe o mantenedor do SQLFiddle respondeu que é um BUG e não terá solução para esta versão, somente para a futura versão sem previsão de data de entrega. Em inglês no seguinte issue do Github : https://github.com/zzzprojects/sqlfiddle3/issues/5

Comment: Valeu Rafael, não era essa a perspectiva que planejei como retorno, mas o que me resta é aguardar. Sua resposta e busca foi essencial. Abraços!

Answer (score 4):

O SQL Fiddle, talvez por segurança não deixa executar a chamada da procedure na aba de execução.

a mensagem é exatamente esta;
***DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.***

Traduzindo
***Instruções DDL e DML não são permitidas no painel de consulta do MySQL; somente instruções SELECT são permitidas. Coloque DDL e DML no painel do esquema.***

Comment: Charles, respondi abaixo que este problema parece ser um bug no interpretador da ferramenta usando MySQL 5.6. Na versão MySQL 5.5 parecia que estava funcionando como apresentado em uma thread em inglês. Adicionamente, como recomentação, sua resposta poderia esta na área de comentários por se tratar de uma observação e tradução e não uma resposta com grau de refino maior. Abs.

Comment: O que a execução de `PRODECURES` impactariam negativamente na segurança do SQLFiddle? A execução de `PROCEDURES` não faria parte de códigos *SQL*?

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nesse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtiCEAeSOYc&t=184s). Não sei por qual motivo essa exceção é lançada. Mas acredito que não seja por segurança

Comment: confirmado BUG no SQLFiddle para MySQL 5.6 no seguinte issue no github  https://github.com/zzzprojects/sqlfiddle3/issues/5